# why there are square gathering at top left corner in this...div painting

Tags: javascript, css

I can't figure out why...what am i doing wrong.

For some reasons elements with 0,0 are being created at top.

http://jsfiddle.net/6UamQ/

```
var m = $('.main'), div = $(document.createElement('div')), d;


m.on('mousemove',function(e){
    d = div.clone();
    d.addClass('paint');
    d.css({top:e.offsetY,left:e.offsetX});
    m.append(d);
});
```

Comment: Your offestX/Y come out to 0/1 sometimes, see the logs: http://jsfiddle.net/qwertynl/6UamQ/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that once you've added the `div`'s to `main`, you may get `mousemove` events from those child elements as well. Try filtering out those child events like this:

```
m.on('mousemove',function(e){
    if( e.target === this ) {
        d = div.clone();
        d.addClass('paint');
        d.css({top:e.offsetY,left:e.offsetX});
        m.append(d);
    }
});
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/6UamQ/3/)

Comment: that slipped my mind...man having someone look at you and what you are trying to do from some distance can solve weirdest problems.

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you replace offsetY and offsetX with pageY and pageX.
http://jsfiddle.net/6UamQ/4/

```
var m = $('.main'), div = $(document.createElement('div')), d;


m.on('mousemove',function(e){
d = div.clone();
d.addClass('paint');
d.css({top:e.pageY,left:e.pageX});
m.append(d);
});
```